# Add multiple lines as Y axis title in chartJs

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I was trying to add a multiple-lined title for the Y-axis in my chart created by chartJs. I could find that the whole title for the chart can use an array of strings to do so but did not find any option to do the same for any of the axes.

I have used the following option to sow the title currently:

```
 scales: {
  yAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: "Deviation from average \n Total" //Multi line label
      },
    }
  ],
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-and-line-ij46gb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) repro of the same.

Current output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to update to version 3 of the lib to use this feature, here you can specify the text of the scale title also as an array to make it multi lined.

The angular wrapper stable build only supports v2 atm, they have a beta build available for v3 so you will need to install the wrapper with the `next` tag behind it to install the beta version or specify the version you want in your package.json

Plain example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: ['first line', 'second line'] // array so it becomes multi lined
        },
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-opXrgVcTHsEVdBUZqTPlW9S8+99hNbaHmXtAdXXc61OUU6gOII5ku/PzZFqexHXc3hnK8IrJKHo+T7O4GRIJcw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```