# How to display multiple y axis titles on seperate lines and rotated 90 degrees clockwise in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, chart.js

**EDIT**

My goal is to display several y axis titles on separate lines rotated 90 degrees clockwise in chartjs.

I want the green circled title to be rotated to the orientation of the red circled title while keeping the multi-line title [image].

The default orientation for multiple titles is the orientation shown in the green circle.

I want the **title** to be on separate lines (like in the green circle) and rotated 90 degrees clockwise (like the orientation of the red circle).

To get the title on separate lines I essentially create an array of strings like so: [Add multiple lines as Y axis title in chartJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367797/add-multiple-lines-as-y-axis-title-in-chartjs)

```
y: {
   stacked: true,
   title: {
      text: ['Project1', 'Number of defects', 'Project2'],
      display: true
   }
}
```

The above code gives the correct title on separate lines but not in the correct orientation.

One solution to rotate the title 90 degrees clockwise is to add a custom title constant and add it as a plugin in the config as follows: [Ability to rotate y axis title in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71379551/ability-to-rotate-y-axis-title-in-chart-js)

```js
const customTitle = {
    id: 'customTitle',
    beforeLayout: (chart, args, opts) => {
        const {display,font} = opts;
        if (!display) {
            return;
        }
        const {ctx} = chart;
        ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
        const {width} = ctx.measureText(opts.text);
        chart.options.layout.padding.left = width * 1.1;
    },
    afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
        const {font,text,color} = opts;
        const {ctx,chartArea: {top,bottom,left,right}} = chart;
        if (opts.display) {
            ctx.fillStyle = color || Chart.defaults.color
            ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
            ctx.fillText(text, 3, (top + bottom) / 2)
        }
    }
}

const labels = ['2021-06-07 00:00:00', '2021-06-08 00:00:00', '2021-06-09 00:00:00'];

const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Fixed defects',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
        data: ['2', '73', '34'],
        barThickness: 5
    }, {
        label: 'Open defects',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        data: ['0', '5', '2'],
        barThickness: 5

    }]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                min: '2021-06-07 00:00:00',
                max: '2021-09-10 00:00:00',
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'week'
                },
                stacked: true,
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true,
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            customTitle: {
                display: true,
                text: ['Project1', 'Number of defects', 'Project2']
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [customTitle]
};

const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas height="100px" id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

The above code Snippet gives the correct orientation but does not display the titles on separate lines.

However when I try to combine both solutions together I get:

- The correct rotated 90 degrees title (but not on separate lines) as shown in the red circle on the left

and

- Multiple titles on separate lines (but not rotated 90 degrees clockwise) as shown in the green circle on the right.

```js
const customTitle = {
    id: 'customTitle',
    beforeLayout: (chart, args, opts) => {
        const {display,font} = opts;
        if (!display) {
            return;
        }
        const {ctx} = chart;
        ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
        const {width} = ctx.measureText(opts.text);
        chart.options.layout.padding.left = width * 1.1;
    },
    afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
        const {font,text,color} = opts;
        const {ctx,chartArea: {top,bottom,left,right}} = chart;
        if (opts.display) {
            ctx.fillStyle = color || Chart.defaults.color
            ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
            ctx.fillText(text, 3, (top + bottom) / 2)
        }
    }
}

const labels = ['2021-06-07 00:00:00', '2021-06-08 00:00:00', '2021-06-09 00:00:00'];

const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Fixed defects',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
        data: ['4', '10', '23'],
        barThickness: 5
    }, {
        label: 'Open defects',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        data: ['43', '7', '1'],
        barThickness: 5

    }]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                min: '2021-06-07 00:00:00',
                max: '2021-09-10 00:00:00',
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'week'
                },
                stacked: true,
            },
            y: {
                    title: {
                    text: ['Project1', 'Number of defects', 'Project2'],
                  display: true
                },
                stacked: true,
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            customTitle: {
                display: true,
                text: ['Project1', 'Number of defects', 'Project2']
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [customTitle]
};

const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas height="100px" id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the fiddle to the same code snippet if you prefer testing it there: [Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LiamTitan/bwey13gr/)

I also tried adding new lines in the custom rotated title like so:

```
customTitle: {
   display: true,
   text: 'Project1\nNumber of defects\nProject2'
}
```

But that didn't work either. How can I get **both** the separate lines title and the correct orientation?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. The first answer you're showing already does both: multiple lines, and rotated by 90°. What are you trying to do instead? Did you mean to *also* make it blue? Because the thing you seem to ask for is this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k84gxove/ (which I got by removing the secondary blue Y title plugin)

Comment: The first answer only shows multiple titles, not rotated by 90 degrees as you can see in code snippet 1 the titles are not rotated 90 degrees clockwise

Comment: Running the first snippet in your question in Firefox gives me multiline and rotated Y title. When I run your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ja6480md/) in Firefox I get a non-rotated, single line blue title and a black rotated, multi-line title.

Comment: That fiddle you share does have not have the y axis title rotated 90 degrees clockwise

Comment: Screenshot from my fiddle: https://i.imgur.com/TSeY2oh.png Do you mean not clockwise as in counterclockwise?

Comment: @ChrisG that screenshot doesn't have the titles rotated 90 degrees clockwise though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242826/discussion-between-liam-and-chris-g).

Comment: Nah, I don't know how to rotate it in the other direction. I don't even get how the first answer does any rotation.

Comment: The first answer achieves 90 degrees rotation by using a custom title but can't achieve multi-line title. The second answer achieves multi-line title but no 90 degrees rotation.

Comment: For some reason I assumed that the vertical title is the rotated title. It's obviously the default thing that chart does. Sorry. Give me a sec.

Comment: That's exactly it, sorry I should have made that clearer, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra check if it is an array, in which case you first only calculate the padding for the longest element so you dont have a big white space, after that you can calculate the Y starting position and increase it for each element in the array so you can have as many lines as you want

```js
const customTitle = {
  id: 'customTitle',
  beforeLayout: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      display,
      font
    } = opts;
    if (!display) {
      return;
    }
    const {
      ctx
    } = chart;
    ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'

    let width = 0;

    if (Array.isArray(opts.text)) {
      opts.text.forEach(e => {
        const tmpWidth = ctx.measureText(e).width;
        if (tmpWidth > width) {
          width = tmpWidth;
        }
      });
    } else {
      width = ctx.measureText(opts.text).width;
    }
    chart.options.layout.padding.left = width * 1.1;
  },
  afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      font,
      text,
      color
    } = opts;
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: {
        top,
        bottom,
        left,
        right
      }
    } = chart;
    if (opts.display) {
      ctx.fillStyle = color || Chart.defaults.color
      ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'

      if (Array.isArray(text)) {
        const height = ctx.measureText("M").width;
        let y = ((top + bottom) / 2) - Math.ceil(text.length / 2) * height;

        text.forEach(e => {
          ctx.fillText(e, 3, y);
          y += height + (opts.lineSpacing || 0);
        });

      } else {
        ctx.fillText(text, 3, (top + bottom) / 2)
      }
    }
  }
}

const labels = ['2021-06-07 00:00:00', '2021-06-08 00:00:00', '2021-06-09 00:00:00'];

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Fixed defects',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    data: ['4', '10', '23'],
    barThickness: 5
  }, {
    label: 'Open defects',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    data: ['43', '7', '1'],
    barThickness: 5

  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: '2021-06-07 00:00:00',
        max: '2021-09-10 00:00:00',
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'week'
        },
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      customTitle: {
        display: true,
        text: ['Project1', 'Number of defects', 'Project2'],
        lineSpacing: 8
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [customTitle]
};

const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas height="100px" id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LeeLenalee I've marked your answer as accepted as it is more flexible although in this case it didn't need to be because it was always going to be those two array entries, but it is better coding practice and could help someone else so thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Thanks for the better answer @LeeLenalee I've deleted my answer as it didn't work in all cases and yours solved the same problem. Thank you for giving me tips on how to improve.